# ValueError: View didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, request

```
def frontblog(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
       for post in Posts.objects(tags=request.POST('search')):
           posttitle=post.post_title
           postcont=post.post_content
           postdate=post.post_date
           posttag=post.post_tags
        return render_to_response("frontblog.html",
                                  RequestContext(request,
                                  {'post':post}))
```

I have tried to send the data from mongo db database as by search using tag post get retrieved and should be send to display on html page.

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: can you improve the title of the question?

Answer (score 1):

*NB : answer based on badly indented code, so it's a bit of a guessing game... but if you want a correct answer learn to post correctly indented code.*

You start your code with a test on `request.method=='POST'` and everything else is under that branch, which means that if it's a GET request (or PUT or whatever) your view function implicitely returns `None`.

There are quite a few other WTFs in your code but fix this one first. BTW a "search" should be done as GET request, not POST. Also, in a POST request, `request.GET` will most probably be empty. Finally, you DO want to use a `Form` to sanitize user inputs... Well, unless you don't mind your site or app being hacked by the first script-kiddie, that is.